# Update RubyGem dependency from a library using yarn

Tags: node.js, rubygems, yarnpkg, package.json

I have a nodejs project using yarn as the package manager. The project includes a library (Library A), which has a dependency on Library B. Library B has a dependency on a Ruby Gem.

I am trying to figure out how to update the version of the Ruby Gem.

I tried updating Library B to its latest versions in the package.json file using a [resolution tag](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/), but I still can’t get the version of the Ruby Gem I need. Is there a way to update Ruby gems that are nested dependencies? Maybe something equivalent to the “resolutions” tag?

Thanks!

Comment: Yarn is primarily for JS, and therefore isn't compatible with Ruby Gems. It sounds like this package either expects you to install the Gem manually (using the `gem` or `bundle` commands) or is bundling it in with scripts in the JS package. If you can name or link to the packages you're using, I should hopefully be able to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Library A is [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) which has a dependency (Library B) on [tz-offset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tz-offset)

Comment: It seems like `tz-offset` is only using Ruby to generate JSON data in development, so you shouldn't need any gems installed when using it from JS/Yarn.

Comment: I see what you are saying, then I think in my particular case there is no need to update. Thanks for commenting!